# Cordova plugin error: "Uncaught module ... already defined"

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I was getting the following error and my custom plugin wasn't starting.

`"Uncaught module com.example.example-plugin already defined"`

Why is my module getting defined twice?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This error occurred because I copy-pasted code from the generated 'example-plugin.js' back into the original plugin file.

When I added the plugin again, the generated code then got wrapped twice like this:

`cordova.define("com.example.example-plugin", function(require, exports, module) { cordova.define("com.example.example-plugin", function(require, exports, module) { var exec = require('cordova/exec');`

Removing the generated bits from the original example-plugin.js file fixed this.

Answer (score 6):

Just to expand on akiraspeirs answer. The 'example-plugin.js' file is located in the Android folder under Assets/www/plugins/example-plugin/example-plugin.js

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the 2 above answers. Deleting the `www` folder & `platforms/browser` -if running on browser. Then running `ionic cordova prepare browser` built all files again correctly.